# Custom Field Repeating When Using foreach

Tags: custom-field, users, user-meta, avatar, gravatar

I'm trying to display user avatars by login user name using custom fields like this -

[image]

And here's the code -

```
function user_avatar() {

        $name  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_name', true );

        $users = get_user_by( 'login', $name  );

        foreach( (array) $users as $user )

        authors();
}


function authors() {

    $gravatar = get_avatar( $user->user_email , 32 );

    echo $gravatar;

}
```

However, this code repeats avatars in addition to the only one i want printed.

[image]

I need to print only the avatars where's there's a custom field value based on username.

Comment: I might suggest it can be problematic to use a custom field for this. This permits typographic errors, and intentionally incorrect data. Either of which can result in errors.   Is there a reason you need a list of user names, whether they have modified the current document or not? Or, would it be better to calculate a list of names for anybody who has created/modified the current post/page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use multiple users, if you will add usernames comma separated in custom field. try below code.

```
function user_avatar() {
    $user = "";
    $names  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_name', true );
    $user_names = array_map('trim', explode(',', $names));
    if(!empty($user_names))
    {
       foreach ($user_names as $key => $user_name) 
       {
          $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_name  );
          if($user)
          {
              $gravatar = get_avatar( $user->user_email , 32 );
              echo $gravatar;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**Edit :** I also tried -

```
$names  = get_post_custom_values( 'user_name' );
```

I tested this when using the same custom field key **user_name** with different login usernames for each user.

if you want to use get_post_custom_value(); try below

```
function user_avatar() {
        $user = "";
        $names  = get_post_custom_values( 'user_name', get_the_ID() );
        if(!empty($names))
        {
           foreach ($names as $key => $user_name) 
           {
              $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_name  );
              if($user)
              {
                  $gravatar = get_avatar( $user->user_email , 32 );
                  echo $gravatar;
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I use foreach because i might need to display avatars for multiple users. Do i not need to use it?

Comment: so will you add multiple users in custom fields separated by comma ? like user1,user2, user3

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. I think i need to use foreach.

Comment: for multiple users, i have updated my answer. please confirm how you will add multiple user in custom filed?

Comment: Will use the same custom field key user_name and different custom field values will be the login username for each user.

Comment: how will you store username in same custom fields ?

Comment: As seen in my code above for $name or possibly See Edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98063/discussion-between-chetan-vaghela-and-michelle).

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what i needed.

Comment: You’re welcome!